# Best practices for gradle idependent projects without repository

Tags: gradle, build-process, android-gradle-plugin

I have the following projects in different folders:

- Android 1
- WebApp
- Android 2
- Android Library

The dependencies are:

- Android 1 needs WebApp (copied in the assets folder)
- Android 1 needs Android Library
- Android 2 needs Android Library

How do I set this up?

For example I cannot really put the Android Lib in my Android 1 application as subproject, since Android 2 also needs this library.

But if Android Lib is an own project how do I make sure to get the latest build included as library in my Android Apps? (We cannot use a repository to upload the lib to)

So the idea is that every Project above is an own gradle project. But how do I declare the dependencies?
For example, when I build Android App 1, gradle should make sure to build Android Lib and WebApp first. And then of course include Android Lib in the project and copy WebApp into the assets folder.

Hopefully this was not to confusing?

Answer (score 0):

Your options are:

- A single multi-project build
- Separate builds that exchange artifacts via a remote repository (populated by CI server)
- Separate builds that exchange artifacts via a local repository (populated by developer executing  upstream build before downstream build)